# Downloading FIles on Asp.net

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net

this is my code

```
protected void btnUpload_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        string filename = Path.GetFileName(FileUpload1.FileName);
        FileUpload1.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("~/CustomerFiles/") + filename);
        lblResult.Text = "Your File " + filename + " is Succesfull uploaded!";
        //lblFile.Text = FileUpload1.FileName;
        lblFile.Text = "../CustomerFiles/" + filename;
        Page_Load(sender, e);
    }

    catch (Exception)

    {
        lblResult.Text = "Upload Failed";
    }
}
```

I can Upload files but I can't see it in my visual studio 2013.I need to see my uploaded files in order for me to download it and save its filepath to Sql Database.

Comment: What do you mean you don't see it in VS 2013? Try `Show all files` and `Refresh` the folder `CustomerFiles`

Comment: In case you want to see your uploaded files in VS2013 then you need to click on 'Show All Files' in Solution Explorer.

Comment: And if you want to know the path in which the file is saved... then here it is:
    Server.MapPath("~/CustomerFiles/") + filename

Comment: @Bharat where can I see this show all files?I tried right clicking the my CustomerFiles folder and there is no refresh in it.

Comment: @rainalasa - one of the icons at the top of the solution explorer window.

Comment: some times you cant see it in Visual stadio , you can clicked on `CustomerFiles` and choose `Open Folder in Explorer`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This my code to download the file

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string filename = "~/Files/Mastering MeteorJS Application Development.pdf";
        String _fileName = "akash";
        string path = MapPath(filename);
        //byte[] bts = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(path);
        Response.Buffer = true;
        Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
        Response.AddHeader("content-disposition:", "attachment;filename=" + _fileName + ".pdf");
        Response.TransmitFile(path);
        //Response.Close();
    }
```

There is a problem i faced when published the web application.This `Files` folder does not copy on Published folder on visual studio 2010 after publishing the app to file system.so i manually copy the `Files` directory with contents  after published of web application and paste in that dir. now its ok